# How to rename namespace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have this route:

```
 namespace :my_namespace do  
 resource :trip do    
  get 'current'  end 
 end
```

How to rename namespace 'my_namespace' to 'my-namespace'?

> "my_namespace/trip/current" => "my-namespace/trip/current"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change:

```
namespace :my_namespace do
```

To:

```
namespace :"my-namespace" do
```

You must use quotes as symbols do not support hyphens without quotes.

Comment: I have controller with namespace My_Namespace: My_namespace:TripsController.